# Find the percentage of Nulls in each row in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, null, percentage

All, please help with this query.
I need to query couple of tables for users information by number of missing values and percentage of nulls in each row by user and by department.
Employees need to register in this information to the system. Basically We need to report that the missing values Employees have fed to system.
For instance; Query Results

```
COL_1  |COL_2  |COL_3 |COL_4 |count  %   d%
----------------------------- ------------
 user1 | dept1 | NULL |   X  |1      50      
 user2 | dept2 | NULL | NULL |2      100
 user3 | dept1 |   X  |   X  |0      0
 user4 | dept2 | NULL |   X  |1      50
```

Appreciate if you could help me with this query. thanks.

Comment: So col_1 to col_4 are current table data, and now you want those two rightmost columns to be calculated?

Comment: Thanks jarlh, well the col_1 to col_4 are query results from multiple tables. I need rightmost columns to be calculated. thanks.

Comment: Please post some example data from source tables and results you need to obtain for sample data.

Comment: @Kacper see the OP's comment prior to yours - the input is `COL_1 ... COL_4` and the expected output is those 4 columns with the additional two columns showing the count of the number of null values and the percentage of null values for `COL_3` and `COL_4`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t.*,
       NVL2( COL_3, 0,  1 ) + NVL2( COL_4, 0,  1 ) AS "Count %",
       NVL2( COL_3, 0, 50 ) + NVL2( COL_4, 0, 50 ) AS "d%"
FROM   table_name t
```

Comment: Hi MTO, Can you please provide this query in Oracle? thanks

Comment: @FelixZ This is an Oracle query.

Answer (score 0):

```
  SELECT a.col_1
       , a.col_2
       , COUNT (*) "count"
       , SUM (CASE WHEN a.col_3 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / COUNT (*) * 100 "d%"
    FROM table1 a
GROUP BY col_1, col_2;
```